# How to find out the modulus of vectors in this question (as seen in the image):

Tags: vectors

[image]

A problem I'm facing involves finding out the modulus of vectors. I understand that the modulus of a vector is the square of both the numbers and then the root of it to find the length. I was thinking for part (a) the answer would be 3 + (2*3) which is 9, and then the square root of this which will be 3. I used the same method to do part (b). However, I'm not sure whether what I have done is right, and I am stuck on part (c).

Answer (score 3):

If $$b=2a$$ then we get $$|a+b|=|a+2a|=|3a|=3|a|$$

If $$b=-2a$$ then we get $$3|-a|=3|a|$$

If $a$ is perpendicular to $b$ then $$|a+b|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2=9+16=25$$ and $$|a+b|$$ gives $5$

Comment: Oh, thank you for your answer. However, just to make sure I understood the concept, I had a doubt. If b = -3a, wouldn't it become |a-3a| = |-2a|, which would then become -2|a|, resulting in -6 as the answer. The answer says 6 (I am not so sure of the rules of vectors like what would happen if the number is negative). Also, is there any rule that allows the two variables inside the modulus to be separated as done for part (c)? Thanks once again.

Comment: Note that $$|a-3a|=|-2a|=|-2||a|=2|a|$$

Comment: note that $$(a+b)\cdot (a+b)=(a+b)^2=|a+b|^2$$ if $$\cdot$$ means dot product.

Comment: Oh yes I get the second part. However, I didn't exactly understand how |−2||| would become 2||.

Comment: We have this law also with real numbers and $$|-2|=2$$, by definition is it $$-(-2)=2$$

Comment: Btw, what does $V11$ mean?

Comment: Oh, it's just a random name I selected, didn't give much thought to it. Thank you for the answer. I have understood now.

Comment: Ok, have a nice day with your vectors!